# Content not displaying in each respective tab

Tags: html

I have  created a simple tab panels. The only problem is, when I click on each tab, the content does not display accordingly (which is suppose to be displayed in each tab). Instead all contents are displayed without being selected first. What I want is, when I click on the profile tab, I want only the content of profile displayed. But in this case, all of them are displayed instead. Below is my simple code. tqs.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body>

section {display:none;}
section:target {display:block;}





  <ul id="profileTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#match" data-toggle="tab">My Match</a></li>
</ul>


<article class="tabs">
 <section id='profile'>
    <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
  </section>
  <section id='about'>
    <p>Hi, this is the second tab.</p>
  </section>
  <section id='match'>
    <p>Hi, this is the third tab.</p>
  </section>
</article>


</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-tabs-using-target-selector/

Comment: Do you know JavaScript?

Comment: I know a little. Can you point me where I'm wrong in the code above?tq

Comment: And please @Nabi. Please don't use links as answer (it is very morally low and low quality).

Comment: Please explain here directly @Nabi which is more convenient.

Comment: @ml2 that's your `stylesheet` :) `<style>section {display:none;} section:target {display:block;}</style>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/sfL7kd3h/

```css
section {display:none;}
section:target {display:block;}
```

```html
<ul id="profileTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#match" data-toggle="tab">My Match</a></li>
</ul>


<article class="tabs">
 <section id='profile'>
    <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
  </section>
  <section id='about'>
    <p>Hi, this is the second tab.</p>
  </section>
  <section id='match'>
    <p>Hi, this is the third tab.</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Tq for the answer. the section was css.